# my custom.css file showing different with ssl and non-ssl urls magento 2

Tags: php, css, magento, ssl, magento2

I have added the custom.css on my magento 2.1.2 website and I have enabled the secure urls, but my css changes are not showing correct on ssl url. My custom.css file showing different with ssl and non-ssl urls.

Any help will be appreciate. Looking forward for quick solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this command from command line.

```
 1. php bin/magento cache:clean
 2. php bin/magento cache:flush
 3. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
 4. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 5. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

And then try to open site.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. but i have already tried all these commands many time but my changes not showing after changing the domain.